# how to make my server support APNs?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

i read in some stackOverflow post that The host would need to have port 2195 open and support push notifications under apns.how do i make my server to support apns.

what does this line means in Push Notification guide

**To establish a trusted provider identity, we should 
present this certificate to APNs at connection time using peer-to-peer authentication.**

do i need to make a connection to APns through my native app? someone please explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much any server that doesn't have restriction on what sockets you can open is ready to be an APNS provider.  In your project code, you can just open a socket to Apple servers (or use a library).

My understanding that Google App Engine and basically any traditional shared web hosting block any port other than 80, so you cannot use them.  However, you can look into [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) that provides a RESTful API that basically use from any service.  It might get pricy though.

Comment: what if i don't want to use urban airship.i have my own server just want to know that do i have to pay for sending notification to iphone devices or just send the payload to apple's getway......?

Comment: You don't need to pay to send notifications.  What language are using to build your back-engine?  We can provide with sample projects for sending notifications.

Comment: i just have created my native iphone app.here what i actually want to do.in my app user starts a countdown timer.as timer started suppose it started on 35 minutes,so send a request to server to show notification when 10 minutes left even app is closed.also if app is already running the alert shows from within application not from the APNs.also tell me how do i manage all the requests,how do i cancel the request from being sent to APNs.thanks for your answer

Comment: is there a step by step guide available after creating application.waht are the steps to use push notification,if there is no guide could you please explain this in a step by step manner.i'm totally noob in this field so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to establish an SSL connection, and then send the payload in the pre-defined binary format.

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Art/aps_provider_binary.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Art/aps_provider_binary.jpg)

See [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/RemoteNotificationsPG.pdf) for more details.

Comment: do i need to pay for sending remote notification? how do i authenticate my own server to APNs?

Comment: the guide details that information, your company must be registered with apple as an iPhone developer

Answer (score 0):

I use appengine, so I solved this by renting a super cheap server in hetzner.de. It basically serves as proxy to my appengine app and uses this library: https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

that library has a one line way to send the message, using the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Google just opened up the ability to do Socket stuff on AppEngine, so I created a sample project that you can use to send push notifications using GCM and APNS in python.  Feel free to use any of it that you like.

I've also included a sample iOS project and Android project that hook up nicely with the app engine solution.

https://github.com/GarettRogers/appengine-apns-gcm

** Full Disclosure **  this is my project, and I'm in no way trying to promote it because it's mine... it's simply the only available project that solves your problem at the moment.  If you find anything that does a better job, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out `java-apns-gae`.

It's an open-source Java APNS library that was specifically designed to work (and be used) on Google App Engine.

https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/java-apns-gae