# How to create a server for APNs for iphone

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating an iPhone app that produce Pushnotifications. When I went through the documents and tutorials, I can see that we need a server support to provide the push notification. So, what are the requirements or what all are the important things that I should keep in mind when I create the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing it on your own, take a look at [how to make my server support APNs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554531/how-to-make-my-server-support-apns)

You can use php-apns if you want readymade server.

Comment: Follow instructions mentioned in this document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/RemoteNotificationsPG.pdf